# fsm aiogram бот вводит старые данные

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

кусок кода бота для записи на сеанс к массажисту. первый раз пишу на aiogram (да и вообще первый мой более менее серъёзный прожект)

в колбек приходят данные переменная data получает дату и время записи на сеанс.
все записывается, но после того как пользователь заново запускает бот посредствам /start
то данные из переменной data остаются неизменными т.е. если человек записался на 12.00
то и после команды старт время остается тем же 12.00
как стереть предыдущие данные?

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.split('/')[0] == 'day')
async def calback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    date_true = call.data.split('/')[1]
    date_week = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_true).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    main(date_week)
    open_empty = cur.execute('SELECT time_data FROM time_seance').fetchall()
    if open_empty == []:
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'на сегодня все занято, попробуйте записаться на другой день')
    else:
        count = cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM time_seance WHERE id>0')
        con.commit
        for i in count:
            logo = open('massage2_edited.jpg', 'rb')
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            for n in open_empty:
                time_day = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(n[0]).strftime("%H:%M")
                f = types.InlineKeyboardButton(time_day, callback_data=('time/' + n[0]))
                markup.row(f)
        await bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, logo, caption=f'Выберите время для записи на сеанс',
                             reply_markup=markup)
        await bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)


class PhoneNumber(StatesGroup):
    phoneNumber = State()
    dataDay = State()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.split('/')[0] == 'time')
async def calback1(call: types.CallbackQuery,state: FSMContext):
    id_fn = call.from_user.first_name
    id_un = call.from_user.username
    id_ln = call.from_user.last_name

    data = call.data.split('/')[1]+'+06:00'
    # data=await PhoneNumber.phoneNumber.set(data1)
    a = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    phone = await call.message.answer('введите номер телефона в формате "+77771233223" или "87771233223"',
                                      reply_markup=a)
    # await state.finish()
    await PhoneNumber.phoneNumber.set()

    @dp.message_handler(state=PhoneNumber.phoneNumber)
    async def phone(message, state: FSMContext ):
        # await PhoneNumber.phoneNumber.set()
        phone = message.text
        await write(message, id_fn, id_un, id_ln, phone, data)
        # await state.finish()
        await state.reset_state()
        # await state.finish()


    @dp.message_handler()
    async def write(message, id_fn, id_un, id_ln, phone, data):
        if len(message.entities)==1:
            for i in message.entities[0]:
                if i[1] == 'phone_number':
                    await auth_calendar(message, id_fn, id_un, id_ln, phone, data)

        else:
        # print('err')
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неверно введен номер телефона')
            time.sleep(3)
            await calback1(call)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы не сохранили значение в FSM

```
await state.update_data(number=message.text)
```

более подробно в примере в официальной документации

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html